# Errore: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: Cannot find encoding

Tags: ios, magento

I am trying to consume Magento SOAP API in Objective-C iOS.

I can able to call Login API and get SessionID but when I try to call cart.info API with same SessionID then it is giving me following error.

> Errore: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: Cannot find encoding.

Comment: make sure you are using the correct syntax http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cart/cart.info.html

Comment: Hi Javier , I am using correct syntax for every API, What expect problem is , When I add single product in cart and call cart.info then I return correct response but when I add bundle Products into cart and call cart.info for getting cart info ,then it gives above error..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [\*\*SOAP-ERROR:\*\* Encoding: Cannot find encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53308593/soap-error-encoding-cannot-find-encoding)