# **SOAP-ERROR:** Encoding: Cannot find encoding

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I gotta consume a SOAP service from PHP but I keep failing to get the response. Maybe it's a problem with the format or the call or idk. I can for example get all the functions names from the server with the **__getFunctions()** method. But when I try to invoke any function I keep getting:

> SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: Cannot find encoding

Below is the code.

```
$wsdl = "https://testing.memoryefactura.com/Memory.FEManager/WebService/CFEService.svc?wsdl";


$parameters = array('Rut' => 'XXXXX',
    'CommerceCode' => 'XXXXX',
    'TerminalCode' => 'XXXXX',
    'Timeout' => 5000);


$options = array(
    'style' => SOAP_RPC,
    'use' => SOAP_ENCODED,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'connection_timeout' => 15,
    'trace' => true,
    'exceptions' => true,
);
try {
    $soap = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
    $HeaderSecurity = array(
        'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array(
            'http' => array(
                'header' => array('username' => 'XXXXX',
                    'password' => 'XXXXX'
                )
            ),
        )),
    );
    $header[] = new SoapHeader("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd", "Security", $HeaderSecurity);

    $soap->__setSoapHeaders($header);
    $data = $soap->Ping($parameters);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}

var_dump($data);
```

Comment: First thing, get rid of `style` and `use` from your options, they should not be used in WSDL mode. Instead of catching `Exception` try catching `SoapFault` which can give you more error details: http://php.net/manual/en/soapfault.soapfault.php

Comment: And are you really supposed to pass HTTP headers named `username` and `password`???

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Erased **style** and **use** and still the same. Tried catching soupFault and it gives nothing usefull (just this: `SoapClient->__call('Ping', Array) #1 {main}`). Yes, if i dont send those headers gives authentication error.

Comment: You need to use the specific functions for `SoapFault` to get additional details, not just `getMessage()`.

Comment: Can you share a link to the WSDL?

Comment: Edited the question and added the link in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the wsdl, the ping method takes only 3 parameters.

```
class Ping {
    /** @var BaseMessage */ public $message;
}
class BaseMessage {
    /** @var string */  public $CommerceCode;
    /** @var string */  public $TerminalCode;
    /** @var int */ public $Timeout;
}
```

Also, you incorrectly set the authorization header. The correct way to do this:

```
$wsdl = "https://testing.memoryefactura.com/Memory.FEManager/WebService/CFEService.svc?wsdl";

$opts = [
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false
    ],
    'http' => [
        'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
    ]
];

$params = [
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'verifypeer' => false,
    'verifyhost' => false,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'trace' => 1,
    'exceptions' => 1,
    'connection_timeout' => 180,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts)
];

try {
    $client = new \SoapClient($wsdl, $params);

    $nameSpace = 'http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd';

    $soapUsername = new \SoapVar(
        'XXXXX',
        XSD_STRING,
        null,
        $nameSpace,
        null,
        $nameSpace
    );

    $soapPassword = new \SoapVar(
        'XXXXX',
        XSD_STRING,
        null,
        $nameSpace,
        null,
        $nameSpace
    );

    $auth = new \stdClass();
    $auth->Username = $soapUsername;
    $auth->Password = $soapPassword;

    $soapAuth = new \SoapVar(
        $auth,
        SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
        null,
        $nameSpace,
        'UsernameToken',
        $nameSpace
    );

    $token = new \stdClass();
    $token->UsernameToken = $soapAuth;

    $soapToken = new \SoapVar(
        $token,
        SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
        null,
        $nameSpace,
        'UsernameToken',
        $nameSpace
    );

    $security = new \SoapVar(
        $soapToken,
        SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,
        null,
        $nameSpace,
        'Security',
        $nameSpace
    );

    $header = new \SoapHeader($nameSpace, 'Security', $security, true);

    $client->__setSoapHeaders([$header]);

    $parameters = array(
        'CommerceCode' => 'XXXXX',
        'TerminalCode' => 'XXXXX',
        'Timeout' => 5000
    );

    $data = $client->Ping($parameters);
} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    echo "REQUEST:\n" . $client->__getLastRequest();
    die("\nFaultcode: " . $fault->faultcode . "\nFaultstring: " . $fault->faultstring);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Thanks man! It throws **Faultcode: a:InternalServiceFault Faultstring: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**, any clue?

Comment: Don't worry, `$data = $client->Ping(array('message' => $parameters));` solved it. Thanks a lot man, saved my neck!